# Is it possible to restrict an IAM user to certain functions inside an AWS ECS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm wondering if something is possible inside AWS ECS.  I want to create a cluster and then allow multiple users to create containers inside that cluster.

However, I want to make sure that each user stays in their lane. i.e.: that they can create containers and only destroy or manage their own.

Ideally, I'd also be able to control how many containers they create.

Is it possible to do this via IAM policies and assign each user their own IAM id?

Comment: Do you've any mechanism for identifying the owner?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *IAM policies are used to control access to these mechanisms, but they do not provide direct control over the number of containers running in ECS.*

However, you can create a custom IAM policy that effectively restricts the user to a selection of actions within a given ECS cluster.

The following IAM policy example, allows the user to run tasks on the specified ECS cluster, stop their own tasks, and deregister their own task definitions.

Please replace the following placeholders with your specific values:

- region: The AWS region where your ECS cluster is located (e.g.,
  us-east-1).
- account-id: Your AWS account ID.
- cluster-name: The name of your ECS cluster.
- username: The IAM username of the user you want to grant these permissions to.
- task-definition-family: The family name of the task definition.
- task-definition-revision: The revision number of the task definition.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ECSRunTask",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:RunTask"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:cluster/<cluster-name>"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ECSStopTask",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:StopTask"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:task/<cluster-name>/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "ecs:CreatedBy": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/<username>"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ECSDeregisterTaskDefinition",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:DeregisterTaskDefinition"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:task-definition/<task-definition-family>:<task-definition-revision>"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "ecs:CreatedBy": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/<username>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want to scale this, create IAM groups, add users, and attach the policy.

This should do the trick:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ECSRunTask",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:RunTask"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:cluster/<cluster-name>"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ECSStopTask",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:StopTask"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:task/<cluster-name>/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalTag/GroupName": "<group-name>"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "ECSDeregisterTaskDefinition",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:DeregisterTaskDefinition"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:<region>:<account-id>:task-definition/<task-definition-family>:<task-definition-revision>"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:PrincipalTag/GroupName": "<group-name>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```